# Lost in the YouTube API

Tags: php, json, youtube

I've been working with a couple of API's before like Vimeo, Dribbble and Twitter. Now I am trying out YouTube's API. But the complexity of the API gets me lost.

I've been going through parts of it and reading up on a couple of tutorials but can't seem to find what I want.

They say something about zend_gdata but I don't understand what that has to do with YouTube's API and can't seem to get it work either.

**This is what I want to accomplish:**

Get video data for each video from [playlist] by [user]:

- Video poster (big thumbnail)
- Title
- Description
- Embed code (iframe probably)

I am using PHP and prefer an output in JSON.

Can you guys point me out where to start (tutorial, which API, ...) to accomplish this rather simple task?

**EDIT**

Example for Vimeo: http://vimeo.com/api/v2/channel/52750/videos.json

Which URL can I CURL for YouTube to get al videos in a specified playlist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Data API Protocol site](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists.html#Retrieving_a_playlist):

> As noted in the previous section, each entry in a user's playlists feed contains a  tag that specifies the URL for retrieving the list of videos in the playlist. The following example shows the URL for retrieving a playlist as that URL appears in a playlists feed entry:

```
<content type='application/atom+xml' src='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/8BCDD04DE8F771B2?v=2'/>
```

So the url is something like this:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLAYLISTID?v=2

**Update**

For JSON format, add `&alt=json` GET parameter at the end of the url:

`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLAYLISTID?v=2&alt=json`

Comment: That's great, exactly what I need but is there a JSON variant?

Comment: Just add **&alt=json** GET parameter at the end of the url: 
    `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLAYLISTID?v=2&alt=json`

Comment: Great! I was literally lost in the big YouTube API but you pointed me to the right URL. Thanks!